# Safari | Unknown padding / margin-top

Tags: css, safari, margin, padding

I've a little strange issue between Safari and all other browsers. One horizontal div container gets a padding/margin-top. (class: mm)

But I don't know why and where. In Firefox and Chrome it looks normal, but not in Safari.

[image]

```
"https://jsfiddle.net/_Sascha_/0894gkjm/1"
```

Has anyone experience with Safari and know what's happening here?

```css
#test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999999;
}

#test div {
  background: grey;
  display: inline-block;
}

#test .ms, #test .me {
  width: 2px;
  height: 15px;
}

#test .mm {
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100px;
}

#ignoreThis {
  position: relative;
  width: 112px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapThis">
    <div id="test">
        <div class="ms">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="mm">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="me">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version of Safari are you using, on which OS ?

Comment: As a Safari 9.0 user, it's appearing fine to me. https://gyazo.com/9fd94cfa10599ee3a66e1ebb8664bfde

Comment: Include the code in the question, please. As I'm sure you noted when writing the question, "All links to JSFiddle must be accompanied by code" or something like that. I hope you were not just trying to get around the rules by using that weird formatting on the link.

Comment: @Lauromine: Safari 8.0.8

Comment: @ColonelHedgehog: Hope we get the reason and solution for older versions, too. Or is the only version a browser(version)bridge?

Comment: @Roope: The hint should be better explaining what it wants. I did understand, that these links have to get in this code-display shortcut. (ctrl/cmd+k) That doesn't worked and so I did add " to the end and beginning. Sorry for the misunderstanding, I will fix that!